# SQL query to select first rows for each unique pair of values in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a query across two tables and then refine the results to only provide the most recent record based on the greatest time value for each sequence_id.

I've tried many combinations of GROUP BY, ORDER BY, Max(), PARTITION and other suggestions found on SO. Unfortunately, all the solutions I have seen so far only use one table and only return the pair of columns of interest.

Queries I have attempted:

```sql
select a.trip, a.sequence_id, a.time, a.point_id 
from th, ti as a
     inner join (
        select th.trip, max(ti.sequence_id), ti.time, ti.point_id
        from th, ti 
        group by th.trip
     ) as g on g.sequence_id = a.sequence_id


select th.trip, ti.sequence_id, ti.time, ti.point_id 
FROM th, ti 
where ti.sequence_id = th.sequence_id 
AND (row_number() over (partition by th.sequence_id) = 1)
```

Given the tables 'th’ and 'ti'

[image: Table 'th']

[image: Table 'ti']

I need a query that will return ONLY the rows highlighted where for that sequence_id where the time value is greatest.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZUk7.png)

We are using an Oracle database.

I've researched many posts on SO regarding this topic, but could not find any that used multiple tables and returned results for other columns an addition to the value/pair columns.

Comment: The rows that you have highlighted to not agree with the definition you give of what you want.

Comment: "The rows highlighted where for that sequence_id the time value is the greatest" and yet for the `sequence_id` of `68355` the greatest time value is `2018-08-10 10:48:43` where you have highlighted `2017-08-10 10:46:58`. Is your highlighting wrong or your definition?

Comment: I'm also confused about your "Unique Pair of values" and "The most recent record for a pair of columns" but your definition specifically states a single column `sequence_id`. What is the "Pair" that you keep mentioning and how does that "Pair" figure into the logic you are wanting to build? Is this sample data not robust enough or is this not really a "Pair" of columns that we need to take into consideration. Please clarify both points so we can help out.

Comment: The table has been corrected. Sorry for the misleading highlight.

Comment: The first sentence in the description has been modified for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   select * from (
    select th.trip, ti.sequence_id, ti.time, ti.point_id,row_number() over (partition by th.sequence_id order by ti.time desc) rn FROM th, ti 
    where ti.sequence_id = th.sequence_id)
    where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a window function: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/window-functions-usage.html

query will be something like:

```
select trip, sequence_id, time, point_id, 
       row_number() over (partition by sequence_id, trip, point_id order by time desc) as rownum
  from ti inner join th using(sequence_id)
  where rownum = 1
```

above is pseudo-SQL, you can adjust it, but the idea is there.

Answer (score 0):

The query below must help you:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ti.sequence_id, 
    MAX(th.time) OVER (PARTITION BY ti.sequence_id)
FROM ti
INNER JOIN th 
ON ti.sequence_id = th.sequence_id
ORDER BY ti.sequence_id;
```

The `MAX` returns the the maximum **th.time** `OVER` a block of rows. A block of rows `PARTITIONED BY` (or grouped by) field **ti.sequence_id**.

The `ORDER BY` clause is optional and I've put for result to be shown in the order you highlighted.

Hope this helps.